# How to use elastic search queries in windows?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi am new in elastic search, I installed the elastic search in my windows 7 machine but I can't know, how to run and use elastic search queries in windows where should I type the elastic search queries and where should I run this queries?..
Any one know about it help me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

1. via HTTP interface, which means that you can run GET queries via your browser (Firefox, Chrome etc.) by accesing the proper url like:

   http://localhost:9200/_search?q=tag:wow
2. Elasticsearch's [HEAD plugin](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/). You can execute any query with it. It also has multiple additional functionalities.
3. Install [cUrl for Windows](https://www.google.pl/search?q=curl%20for%20windows) and then run queries just like every tutorial suggests.
4. use any programming language like PHP that supports curl library.

Personally I prefer HEAD plugin since it has other functionalities that I use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check sense plugin for chrome. It will also help you in syntax for queries.
you can get it from here

https://github.com/bleskes/sense